# Getting pricing for tickets

Tags: java, math, logic

I am trying to make a simple java program, that calculates how much tickets would cost.
1 adult ticket is 10$, a child cost 5$ but a family ticket (2 adults and 2 children) is 26$. An obvious saving
So when input from the user, it needs to calculate how many family tickets (if applicable) and then pricing of items if they dont fit into a family bundle.

I.e.

- Number of adults: 2
- Number of children: 4
- Number of family tickets: 1
- Number of child tickets: 2
- Total cost: $36

I cannot figure out the logic behind getting the pairings, comparing and taking out the extra items from both adults and children if needed. Here is what ive gotten so far:

```
        double adultPairs,childPairs;
        if (numberAdults <= 1) { 
            adultPairs = 0;
        }
        else if (isEven(numberAdults)) { 
            adultPairs = numberAdults / 2; 
            adultTickets = 0;
        }
        else { 
            adultPairs = numberAdults / 2; 
            adultTickets = 1;
        }

        if (numberChildren <= 1) { 
            childPairs = 0; 
        }
        else if (isEven(numberChildren)) { 
            childPairs = numberChildren / 2; 
            childTickets = 0;
        }
        else { 
            childPairs = numberChildren / 2;
            childTickets = 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this one?

```
int familyTickets = Math.min(adults/2, childs/2);
int adultTickets = adults - familyTickets*2;
int childTickets = childs - familyTickets*2;
```

First line compares the half of adults and childs (rounded down) and returns the minimum value of it. For example, if you have 9 adults and 25 children, it takes 9/2 and 25/2 which is 4 and 12, therefore it returns 4. And thats how much family tickets you want.

In next two lines, you just takes all adults/children and substract the adults/children family tickets, which is number of family tickets multiplied by two.

---

Even without Math.min method, it is quite easy :

```
int familyTickets = 0;

if (adults > childs){
    familyTickets = childs/2;
} else {
    familyTickets = adults/2;
}

int adultTickets = adults - familyTickets*2;
int childTickets = childs - familyTickets*2;
```

---

PS : Also note, that in Java, if you divide integer with integer, it returns another integer "rounded" down (it is not technically rounded, it just cut off anything less than 1) and it is what we need here. This is reason why I do not use double.

Comment: I will try this, and works or not could you explain it alittle further

Comment: I appreciate the edit, makes perfect sense. Works perfectly. I just wasn't aware of the function that you did, but I also couldnt workout the math behind the problem either I appreciate the explaination.